# Ignoring createdAt field when create/update, but return to JSON response

Tags: go, go-gin

I have a struct in Go

```
type ExternalSystem struct {
    ID        uint            `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Name      string          `json:"name" binding:"required"`
    CreatedAt *time.Time      `json:"createdAt" binding:"-"`
    DeletedAt *gorm.DeletedAt `json:"deletedAt" binding:"-"`
}
```

And have controller (route)

```
func CreateExternalSystemAction(c *gin.Context) {
    appG := app.Gin{C: c}

    externalSystem := models.ExternalSystem{}

    if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&externalSystem); err != nil {
        appG.C.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "error": err.Error(),
        })
        return
    }

    db := models2.DB
    db.Create(&externalSystem)

    appG.C.JSON(http.StatusCreated, externalSystem)
}

func UpdateExternalSystemAction(c *gin.Context) {
    appG := app.Gin{C: c}
    db := models2.DB

    var externalSystem models.ExternalSystem

    db.Where("id = @id", sql.Named("id", c.Param("id"))).First(&externalSystem)

    if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&externalSystem); err != nil {
        appG.C.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "error": err.Error(),
        })
        return
    }

    db.Updates(&externalSystem)

    appG.C.JSON(http.StatusOK, externalSystem)
}
```

How can I ignore the completion of the field CreatedAt/UpdatedAt when creating or updating an object? So that the server, and not the client, is responsible for filling in these fields, what does JSON send to me? However, I need the value of this field to go to the client in the response.

Currently, when I send JSON:

```
{
    "name": "System 3",
    "createdAt": "2023-12-25T22:04:10.012034+04:00"
}
```

Gin binding this value to struct.  To summarize again, I want to ignore these fields for writing (when received from the client), but give them in the response for reading.

I tried:

binding:"-", but this doesnt work (biding for validation)

json:"-", but this hide field for response

Comment: Use two structs, one to receive data from client, and one to return it. The first one should not have those fields.

Comment: have you tried **omitempty** on binding/validation tag?

Comment: @BurakSerdar and third for gorm (database storing)? Its crazy :D (previous I use PHP/Symfony framework, and have one model (entity) for data. Serialize to JSON with help serialization groups)

Comment: @hmmftgStandswithPalestine omitempty Is it intended to ensure that if the field is empty, it will not be given response?

Comment: @Юрий use `omitempty` as suggested above, if data field is empty then it wouldn't be given as reponse.

Comment: @AshutoshPandey  This is what I wanted to say. Just reported for @
hmmftg Stands with Palestine that his proposal does not fit the question. The question was not to hide the empty field. The question is not to accept its value from the client, but to send it to the programmatic filling of the field in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought about the solution for a long time. And after reading the comments under my question. I came to an option that completely suits me. However, the approach is still not similar to what I have used in other languages (PHP Symfony, Python Django)

Model

```
type System struct {
    ID        uint
    Name      string
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
}

type InputSystem struct {
    Name string
}

func (inputSystem *InputSystem) Convert() System {
    system := System{
        Name: inputSystem.Name,
    }
    return system
}

func (system *System) Save() (*System, error) {
    err := DB.Create(system).Error

    if err != nil {
        return &System{}, err
    }

    return system, err
}

func (system *System) BeforeSave(*gorm.DB) error {
    system.Name = html.EscapeString(strings.TrimSpace(system.Name))
    return nil
}

func (system *System) BeforeUpdate(*gorm.DB) error {
    system.Name = html.EscapeString(strings.TrimSpace(system.Name))
    return nil
}
```

Controller (route)

```
func CreateSystemAction(c *gin.Context) {

    var inputSystem models.InputSystem

    if err := c.BindJSON(&inputSystem); err != nil {
        c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "error": err.Error(),
        })
        return
    }

    dbSystem := inputSystem.Convert()

    _, err := dbSystem.Save()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, dbSystem)
}
```

If there are better suggestions, I will be glad to receive comments